# php and html form input

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a php code like this

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<FORM action=""  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="1">
<table border=1>
<tr><td>test post</td><td><input type="text" size="60" name="post" value="http://site.com/"></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<INPUT class=submit type="submit" value="[SUBMIT]" name="Submit">
</FORM>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?
if ($_POST['form_action']) {

print_r($_POST['post']);
}
?>
```

i want to print the form post when Some one press the submit button.Where is the problem?

Comment: We typically want to see that some effort has been made on your part to solve the problem yourself. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and what was the result?

Comment: i mentioned about my effort brother.But there is some problem in my code,thats why I am not getting the required output.I thought stackoverflow.com's geniuses will solve my problem,thats why I posted here.

Comment: You need to understand a few things first: there are _two_ processes involved in what you want: 1.) serving an html form and 2.) "printing" the POST variables. You cannot code two things in one run and expect the server to 'magically' do things the way you like.

Comment: @ForceEx You're wrong there, brother. That was in the old days. Today, you already need to be a genius before you can ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code could work.

This line will probably give an error when the form is not posted yet, but it is in the bottom, so the HTML form should be generated already.

```
if ($_POST['form_action'])
```

You can change this to

```
if (array_key_exists('form_action', $_POST))
```

That will correct the check.

After that, the form should work, but mind that the form will be generated again, on each request, and the actual output you `print_r`d is at the bottom of the output. Because it is outside of the html body, it may be rendered at the bottom of the page or it may not be rendered at all.

You should be able to see the output when you View Source the page.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['form_action'])) {

echo($_POST['post']);
}
?>
```

isset looks wheter a variable / key is defined.

This should work. Hope that helps.

Comment: Did you read the snippet he gives at all?

Comment: Yes, why? You could add $_POST['post']. of course. (As I now did)

Comment: He outputs after the closing </html> tag...

Comment: Yes, this is another Problem.

Comment: @arkascha Seems like that's the main problem, since an unset variable will be treated as false in an `if` statement. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for sure..

But i think you should put in much more effort solve these silly problems by yourself..!! :-)

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['form_action'])) {

print_r($_POST['post']);
exit;
}

print '
<html>
<body>
<center>
<FORM action=""  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="1">
<table border=1>
<tr><td>test post</td><td><input type="text" size="60" name="post"     value="http://site.com/"></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<INPUT class=submit type="submit" value="[SUBMIT]" name="Submit">
</FORM>
</center>
</body>
</html>';

?>
```